# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{-9}^9 (e^x-e^{-x}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.4

Can somebody please verify this for me?

Evaluate $\int_{-9}^9 (e^x-e^{-x}) dx$

---

$\int_{-9}^9 (e^x-e^{-x}) dx$

$= \int_{-9}^9e^x\,dx -\int_{-9}^9e^{-x} dx$

$= (e^x|_{-9}^9-\frac{e^{-x}}{-1}|_{-9}^9)$

$= ((e^9-e^{-9})-(\frac{e^{-9}}{-1}-\frac{e^{-(-9)}}{-1}))$

$= e^9-e^{-9}-\frac{e^{-9}}{-1}+\frac{e^{-(-9)}}{-1}))$

$= e^9-e^{-9}+e^{-9}-e^{9}$

$=0$

Comment: That's okay, but it's easier to note that $e^x-e^{-x}$ is an *odd* function.

Comment: You're work is fine.  I say that to affirm your work and J.M.'s comment,  and because your question wasn't answered by the only comment posted as an answer below, but as another commenter noted, whenever $f(x)$ is an odd function, then $$\int_{-a}^a f(x) = 0$$ provided $a$ is a real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd function integrated from $-a$ to $a$ will be $0$.